# Зависает cv2.imshow во время показа numpy array'я

Tags: python, opencv

Пытаюсь вывести чтение рабочего стола в numpy array, а затем, в отдельном потоке, показывать его как изображение. Но получается так, что окно просто зависает и ничего не показывает.

Код:

```
import threading
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time

target_array = None

def x():
    global target_array
    while True:
        if target_array is not None:
            cv2.imshow("hello",target_array)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=x).start()
    while True:
        img = ImageGrab.grab(
            bbox=(100, 100, 1280, 720))  # bbox specifies specific region (bbox= x,y,width,height *starts top-left)
        target_array = np.array(img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            break

    cap.release()


    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Что с этим делать?

P.S Нужно сделать именно в отельном потоке.

[image: пример]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В описании метода  `cv2.imshow` сказано:

> This function should be followed by cv::waitKey function which
>   displays the image for specified milliseconds. Otherwise, it won't
>   display the image.

За этой функцией должна следовать функция `cv.waitKey`, которая отображает изображение указанное количество миллисекунд. В противном случае он не будет отображать изображение.

вам нужно переместить вызов

```
k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
```

в функцию `x` после строки

```
cv2.imshow("hello",target_array)
```

так чтобы она вызывалась после каждого отображения изображения